# What's the most efficient way to replicate data from Postgres (RDS) to AWS Redshift while keeping data integrity

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, replication, amazon-rds

I'm looking for an efficient way to replicate data from AWS RDS to Redshift. Based on my research, copying to s3 and loading it from there seems to be the recommended approach. However, this doesn't guarantee data integrity as it produces duplicate rows sometimes which needs to be deduped. Is there a better way of doing this, without using a third party vendor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.html) to continuously replicate from RDS Postgres to RedShift. You can even alter the schema with the [Schema Conversion Tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Welcome.html) if you need to.